# Translation of "...quae parvas aves capit et est."

Tags: word-request, grammar-identification, latin-to-english-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, esse

I was reading *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata* to practice my fluency of understanding simple sentences. In the tenth chapter, *Bestiae et Homines* (page 69), I came across a description of eagles.

> Aquila est magna avis fera, quae parvas aves capit et est.

I quickly translated it as that which follows.

> An eagle is a large and untame bird, which captures small birds and... is?

I thought that, of course, an eagle might eat smaller birds, but why is *est* used? Can *esse* also mean *to eat*? I checked many online dictionaries, but was unable to find any alternative definitions related to the action of eating.

The words used in this book are very basic, as it's for beginners. I've never discovered a word which I had to look up until now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, it means *[he] eats*; it is a contracted form. It's not very common, nor extremely rare. [Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=edo%231&filter=CUTF8) even call it "very frequent", which I think is an exaggeration:

> The contr. forms *es, est, estis,* etc., are very freq. in prose and poetry: "est", Vergil, *Aeneid* 4, 66; 5, 683; Horace, *Satires* 2, 2, 57

Comment: The initial E is short for "be" and long for "eat" in *esse*, *es*, *est*, *estis*... (Or at least so I have been told repeatedly.) But the quantity is often hidden, so it doesn't help distinguishing the two.

Comment: Hence _ĕs quod ēs_ ‘you are what you eat’.

Comment: I think most etymologists would agree that the "contracted" forms are historically primary and that the "regular" forms are analogical.

Comment: Is this the same as in Russian есть (to eat) vs. есть (is)?

Comment: @Anixx You could ask that as a separate question. It'd be interesting to know how the ambiguities in the two languages are related. (I only saw your comment now.)